# python type hinting callable from certain modules / subclasses

Tags: python

I can use `Callable` to type hint that a parameter is a function itself:

```
from typing import Callable
def myfun(f: Callable):
    pass
```

Could I somehow specify that the `Callable` should be from, e.g. `pandas.DataFrame.agg` (e.g. `sum`)? Is this (not) recommended?

Comment: You can specify the expected *signature* of the callable, it makes little sense to specify that it must be a *specific* function, because then you could just hardcode it.

Comment: To add on @deceze's answer, it is idiomatic in Python to only "enforce" (to the extent type hinting enforces anything) what you expect something does or how it behaves (ie. is it callable, iterable, summable, etc.) rather than what it is exactly (is it a function, a list, a number, etc.). That commonly called duck typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hint the function users to use a certain subset of known functions, I would suggest to use directly an `Enum` of callables.

Something like this:

```py
from enum import Enum
import pandas as pd 


class FunctionAllowed(Enum):

    agg = pd.DataFrame.agg
    sum = pd.DataFrame.sum


def myfun(f:FunctionAllowed):
    a = pd.DataFrame()

    f.value(a)

myfun(FunctionAllowed.sum)
```

Comment: I find it a bit of an overkill to create an enum but gets the job done...